# HTML & CSS: Text on a button

Tags: html, css, button

I have a social media button at the home page of my personal website. Actually it is working pretty well but when I try to add a text on the button (eg. FOLLOW) the text layer makes it unclickable. My code has no JS function involved. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: CSS code added.

Edit #2: Thank you for all the answers. However the `<button>` tag and JS codes didn't work for me in this situation. I finally managed to reduce the text layer area by removing `height` and `width` properties from the `.social-text` class and now the text doesn't affect the button functionality. It still overlaps the button but at a minimum area and doesn't cause an issue anymore. I'm adding a screenshot of fixed button. Happy coding!

[image: ss]

HTML:

```
         <div>
       
         <ul id="menu">
        
             <a class="menu-button icon-plus" href="#menu" title="Show navigation"></a>
             <a class="menu-button icon-minus" href="#0" title="Hide navigation"></a>
             
             <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
                     <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                     <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                     <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="menu-item">
                 <a href="https://linkedin.com/in" target="_blank">
                     <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
         <span class="social-text">FOLLOW</span>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #menu {
     text-align: center;
     width: 11vw;
     height: 11vw;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 23vw;
     margin-left: 23vw;
     margin-top: 6vw;
     list-style: none;
     font-size: 2.5vw;
   }

    .menu-button {
     opacity: 0;
     z-index: -1;
    }
         
    .menu-button {
      width: 11vw;
      height: 11vw;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin: -5.8vw 0 0 -5.8vw;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #424242;
      background-size: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-decoration: none;
     }

     #menu:not(:target)>a:first-of-type,
     #menu:target>a:last-of-type {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1;
     }

     #menu:not(:target)>.icon-plus:before, 
     #menu:target>.icon-minus:before {
       opacity: 1;
     }

     .menu-item {
        width: 5.5vw;
        height: 5.5vw;
        position: absolute;
        left: 55%;
        line-height: 1vw;
        top: 70%;
        margin: -3.9vw 0 0 -3.9vw;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #424242;
        transform: translate(0vw, 0vw);
        transition: transform 500ms;
        z-index: -2;        
        transition: .5s;
       }

       .menu-item:hover{
         opacity: 0.5;
         box-shadow: 0 0.4vw 0.8vw black; 
        }


      .menu-item a {
         color: #fff;
         position: relative;
         top: 30%;
         left: 0;
         text-decoration: none;
       }

      #menu:target>.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
        transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(-11.7vw) rotate(300deg);
        transition-delay: 0s;
      }

      #menu:target>.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
        transform: rotate(20deg) translateY(-12.1vw) rotate(-20deg);
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
      }

     #menu:target>.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
       transform: rotate(-20deg) translateY(-12.1vw) rotate(20deg);
       transition-delay: 0.2s;
     }

     #menu:target>.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
       transform: rotate(-60deg) translateY(-11.7vw) rotate(60deg);
       transition-delay: 0.3s;
     }

     .social-text {
       text-align: center;
       width: 11vw;
       height: 11vw;
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       top: 23vw;
       margin-left: 23vw;
       margin-top: 6vw;
       z-index: 2;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `<button>` ?

Comment: Yes, wrapped the HTML code with <button></button>. Didn't work.

Comment: Do you want the button to be inside the circle?

Comment: Yes, exactly on the button.

Comment: I updated my answer, is this the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `<button>`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn-follow");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("followed");
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-follow">FOLLOW</button>
```

Or you could add a `role="button"` to your span tag

```js
const span = document.getElementById("span-follow");

span.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("followed");
});
```

```html
<span id="span-follow" role="button">FOLLOW</span>
```

If you want to create a circle button, you can create a circle with a `<div>` and use it like a `<button>`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn-follow");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("followed");
});
```

```css
.social-circle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 11vw;
  line-height: 11vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F77;
}

.social-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-circle cursor-pointer" id="btn-follow" role="button">
  <span class="social-text" role="button">FOLLOW</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried your second solution. Wrapped the JS part with a <script> tag in <head>. But when the text overlaps the button, the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a button tag in your span i.e,

```
<span><button class="social-text">Follow</button></span>
```

or either directly use `<button>` no need to add `<span>` . Here goes the JS:-

```
    const btn=document.querySelector('.social-text');
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("Followed");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used the button tag. So, only the 'Follow' text is showing. Try this.

```
<button class="social-text">Follow</button>
```